# Flutter firebase firestore: 'path.isNotEmpty': a document path must be a non-empty string)

Tags: firebase, flutter, chat

im trying to make chat app for my flutter application. But this error is always come up everytime i try to click to chat. [The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c1iP.png)
Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code.

```
readLocal() async {
prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
id = prefs.getString('id') ?? '';
if (id.hashCode <= peerId.hashCode) {
  groupChatId = '$id-$peerId';
} else {
  groupChatId = '$peerId-$id';
}
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(id)
    .update({'chattingWith': peerId});

setState(() {});
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If looks like your `id` variable is an empty string, which isn't a valid document ID to pass into `doc()`.

Given how you initialize `id`:

```
id = prefs.getString('id') ?? '';
```

It seems that `prefs.getString('id')` returns null. You'll want to figure out what you want to do when that happens, but a simple way is to check with:

```
id = prefs.getString('id');
if (!id.isEmpty) {
  if (id.hashCode <= peerId.hashCode) {
    groupChatId = '$id-$peerId';
  } else {
    groupChatId = '$peerId-$id';
  }
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(id)
    .update({'chattingWith': peerId});

  setState(() {});
}
```

Comment: i try like u said. but the error still the same. it said that id.isEmpty is return null

Comment: Can you show the **exact** error message?

Comment: Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isEmpty' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isEmpty)

Comment: Hmmm... that should've failed the same before. But if `id` can be null too, you can check for that with `if (id != null && !id.isEmpty) {` or `if (!id?.isEmpty) {`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of '', I just passed '1' . Issue has been solved. Initially it has to be non empty. It can take any non empty value.