# Flutter firebase firestore: path.isNotEmpty': a document path must be a non-empty string

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

im trying to make doctors app for my flutter application. But this error is always come up everytime i try to click to doctor details. The error Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code.

[image]

Thanks.

Doctor Details File :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:new_project/provider/provider_data.dart';

class DoctorsDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<DoctorsDetail> createState() => _DoctorsDetailState();
}
class _DoctorsDetailState extends State<DoctorsDetail> {
  late  String _nameAR = '';
  @override
  void initState() {
    getDoctorProfile();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(_nameAR,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  getDoctorProfile() async{
    DocumentReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('categories')
        .doc(CategoryID(context))
        .collection('subCategory')
        .doc(SubCategoryID(context));
    ref.get().then(
            (doc) => {
              setState(() {
                if (doc.data() != null ) {
                  _nameAR = (doc.data() as dynamic )['nameAR'] ??='';
                }
              })
      },
    );
  }
}
```

im trying to make doctors app for my flutter application. But this error is always come up everytime i try to click to doctor details. The error Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code.
ProviderData File :

```
class ProviderData extends ChangeNotifier{
  String CategoryID = '';
  String SubCategoryID = '';

  void setCategoryID({required String val}) {
    CategoryID = val;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  void setSubCategoryID({required String val}) {
    SubCategoryID = val;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

//write
setCategoryID({required context, required String val}) {
  Provider.of<ProviderData>(context, listen: false).setCategoryID(val: val);
}
//read
String CategoryID(context) {
  String CategoryID =
      Provider.of<ProviderData>(context, listen: false).CategoryID;
  return CategoryID;
}

//write
setSubCategoryID({required context, required String val}) async {
  Provider.of<ProviderData>(context, listen: false).setSubCategoryID(val: val);
}
//read
String SubCategoryID(context) {
  String SubCategoryID =
      Provider.of<ProviderData>(context, listen: false).SubCategoryID;
  return SubCategoryID;
}
```

Comment: It looks like either `CategoryID(context)` or `SubCategoryID(context)` in this code doesn't have a value `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('categories').doc(CategoryID(context)).collection('subCategory').doc(SubCategoryID(context))`. Set a breakpoint on that line and run the code in a debugger to determine which one it is, and why that happens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter firebase firestore: 'path.isNotEmpty': a document path must be a non-empty string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67665855/flutter-firebase-firestore-path-isnotempty-a-document-path-must-be-a-non-emp)